# Ionic 3 - Show Footer is Segment

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I need assistance with hiding a footer on a page when a certain segment is active.

```
<ion-content>
  <div [ngSwitch]="TicketDetails">

   <div *ngSwitchCase="'ticketInfo'">

   </div>

   <div *ngSwitchCase="'comments'">

   </div>
 </div>
</ion-content>


<ion-footer>
Buttons

</ion-footer>
```

I want to hide the footer when the **comments segment** is selected, only show it when a user is viewing **ticketinfo segment**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ion-footer *ngIf="TicketDetails =='ticketinfo'"></ion-footer>
```

According to the value binded to the ngSwitch, it will show the segment in the ngSwitchCase, so if TicketDetails value was equal to ticketInfo thus it will keep showing, else it will be hidden.

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation or some more details to your answer, simply  adding a line of code doesn't per say help understand OP or future community members the issue or the proposed solution.